# UIWebView Deprecation and App Store Rejection on Xamarin Forms

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Can i fix the following ?

My setup

> Xamarin.iOS Version: 13.16.0.13 (Visual Studio Community)
>
> Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac Version 8.5.2 (build 13)
>
> Xamarin.Forms 4.5.0.617

I follow the instruction here

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=macos#uiwebview-deprecation-and-app-store-rejection-itms-90809

and here

> https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7323#issuecomment-542363338

[image]

to fix this problem

> ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no
>   longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and
>   reliability.

but i get the following error on publish

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: UIWebView Deprecation and Xamarin.Forms : https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/uiwebview-deprecation-xamarin-forms/

Comment: Can you please post your info.plist file? It looks like that the error is not with the WebView, but instead with improper plist config. Look at the first line - `Failed to parse PList data type`

Comment: Thanks @MihailDuchev for your time. My app rejected with ITMS-90809 error from the apple. I following the instruction and now i get this error before publish. I edit my answer with info.plist.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. I don't see anything wrong with the plist file. Is there any change that you have some reference to UIWebView in your code - like some kind of WebViewRenderer?

Comment: @MihailDuchev i dont use the UIWebView control in my app. Some pages uses the Xamarin.Essentials to open the browser.

Comment: I suppose that the Xamarin.Essentials' version is also up-to-date?

Comment: I use the 1.5.2 version. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/release-notes/1.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Microsoft [mentions in the Microsoft blog, this is fixed in Xamarin.Forms 4.6](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-4-6/)

> Now in 4.6, we are updating the bindings to Google’s library. We have
>   improved the styling support for things like, setting a button’s
>   ‘Disabled’ text color. **The latest library also removes the reference
>   to Apple’s deprecated UIWebView.**

So update your Xamarin.Forms to Version 4.6.

Comment: I have upgraded my app to forms 4.6 and still got this error when I tried to submit to the app store. I did a clean build and that didn't help. Is there something else I have to do? I do have a WebView in my project. Does that cause this? If so how do I get it to use the new WKWebView instead?

Comment: Nevermind. Turns out you still need the linker option and somehow mine got removed. This still works.

Comment: @user856232 great to heat that you got it fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Adding --optimize=force-rejected-types-removal in mtouch arguments [works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61701124/8892050). I have submitted to TestFlight and I did not get email about UIWebView removal.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why, but when i changed my app's version number and build number it's worked. Also i create a new app version on App Store Connect.

Same errors in this link helps me

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/172296/app-store-connect-application-loader-publishing-failed-failed-to-parse-altool-output

Is two different errors I believe. The first is from deprecated UIWebView and another error (publish error) showed up after the first rejection from apple.

Thanks.

Comment: I did the same thing and got the same result. This seems to be a false error if you're already using a version of XF higher than 4.6.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but I share my experience on this particular issue I also have. Maybe it would helps.

When pusblishing to Apple App Store Connect a new app after April 1st 2020, apple could reject your app if you are using UIWebView. Apps submitted before have warnings, but thoses app will not be submitable past December 2020.

My app is new and I publishing after April 1st. I had some hard time publishing this app using VS 2019 Mac and the archive process. I don't like it. You can have a green screen during publishing and see nothing on the appstoreconnect. This is because Apple reject your app. See your emails, you have :

ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability

I suggest to use a archive on your disk and use Transporter app to upload it. It has a log view and warns me about build number issue.

Back on my app, I try the mtouch argument --optimized trick but it doesn't work. I tried Don't link, Link SDK only, Link all to be sure. None worked. Apple keep saying I am using UIWebView. I check my code, I cannot see UIWebView anywhere.

So I wanted to try a fresh app from scratch using last version of Xamarin.Forms 4.6 and publish it. I had the same issue message by Apple. Then I add the --optimizer mtouch argument and publish it. Apple was satisfied. So this means that the "patch" is working.

So as my code doesn't have any UIWebView, I think this could be a tiers library... But how to find...  I am try this https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-find-and-remove-uiwebview-uses-in-your-ios-app-d9395f7baacc

The command gives me this :

FirebaseCore
FirebaseCoreDiagnostics
GTMSessionFetcher
GoogleAPIClientForREST
GoogleDataTransport
GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport
GoogleToolboxForMac
GoogleUtilities
PersonalizedAdConsent
                 U _OBJC_CLASS_$_UIWebView
leveldb
libSkiaSharp
nanopb
protobuf

So I presume those libs are not "compatible"...?

I will update if I find something...

Comment: i also used `nm` command in the link to find a list of dependency names but i am pretty sure those names are the pod dependencies. and i checked all the dependency files that i can't find any files with UIWebView. so why?

Comment: Did you find anything related to the firebase libraries?