# Xamarin Forms UIWebView Deprecation on iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, uiwebview, app-store-connect, deprecated

I have followed advice from the following article:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/uiwebview-deprecation-xamarin-forms/

I am using the correct versions of:
- Xamarin Forms @ 4.6.0.726
- Xamarin iOS @ 13.16.0.13

I have set the flag in the mTouch arguments as --optimize=experimental-xforms-product-type --warn-on-type-ref=UIKit.UIWebView

I have set the Linker to 'Link Framework SDKs Only'

However I still receive the email from Apple stipulating the issue with UIWebView.

This leads me to believe that my code still has references to the UIWebView somewhere.

The warnings I get for this 4x - Warning MT1502: One or more reference(s) to type 'UIKit.UIWebView' already exists inside 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' before linking

But I don't know how to go ahead and find then remove these references.

Please can somebody offer some help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems as though --optimize=experimental-xforms-product-type does not strip out references to UIWebView from Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS. When using --optimize=force-rejected-types-removal it works. I've submitted to Apple and I did not get the email about UIWebView removal.

Comment: Hi , you can update this in answer , then other people will see that easily :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems as though --optimize=experimental-xforms-product-type does not strip out references to UIWebView from Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS. When using --optimize=force-rejected-types-removal it works. I've submitted to Apple and I did not get the email about UIWebView removal.

Comment: I tried  --optimize=force-rejected-types-removal but it did not seem to work, still got rejected by Apple for the UIWebView.
i came accross this article https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/963743/azure-devops-pipeline-upgrade-to-visual-studio-for.html
which said to make sure you are using SDK 6_8_0 instead of 6_6_0.  after making that change (to use 6_8_0)  --optimize=experimental-xforms-product-type works and my app was accepted by apple.
anyone else who reads this, hopefully one of these 2 options works for you!