# Using xamarin forms, still getting warning for UIWebView deprecation in app store "ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, uiwebview, wkwebview

I have removed all UIWebView references and using WKWebView now.
I am hoping any  one will help me as I am stuck.

The apple depreciation warning still
persists even after following the above steps in
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/uiwebview-deprecation-xamarin-forms/.

My nugets are updated as per the article. And removed "obj" and "bin" folders from
ios project to just not use previous references.

I have following details:

MacMini
OS: macOS-10.15 (Catalina)
Visual Studio: 8.6.2
Xamarin.iOS: 13.18.2.1
XCode: 11.5
Xamarin.Forms: 4.8.0.1269
Xamarin.Forms.Maps: 4.8.0.1269
Xamarin.Essentials: 4.5.3.2
Xamarin.Auth: 1.7.0

But it still giving me

> UIKit.UIWebView reference in following dll

> One or more reference(s) to type ‘UIKit.UIWebView’ still exists inside
> ‘Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

> One or more reference(s) to type ‘UIKit.UIWebView’ still exists inside ‘Xamarin.Auth,
> Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

> One or more reference(s) to type UIKit.UIWebView still exists inside
> ‘Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

> One or more reference(s) to type ‘UIKit.UIWebView’ still exists inside ‘Xamarin.Auth,
> Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

At this stage, I cannot figure out what I am missing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UIWebView Deprecation and App Store Rejection on Xamarin Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61613670/uiwebview-deprecation-and-app-store-rejection-on-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I fixed my issue by removing Xamarin Auth package. And also set mTouch argument to AppStore/iPhone iOS build configuration. It is working now. I didn't get any warning message from apple.

Answer (score 3):

As it says in the error message that you are getting,

> One or more reference(s) to type ‘UIKit.UIWebView’ still exists inside ‘Xamarin.Auth,

So, you need to stop using "Xamarin.Auth" as it still references UIWebView.

There's also an [issue filed in the Github](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/issues/423) of that nuget. Even though there's a [PR already submitted](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/pull/443) to fix that issue, but they are not going to fix it because Xamarin.Auth is not safe for use. They have made it clear that the library is deprecated, so you have to start using the [SecureStorage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage) provided by Xamarin Essentials. They even wrote a [migration guide](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/wiki/Migrating-from-AccountStore-to-Xamarin.Essentials-SecureStorage) to help you with this.

So, please migrate and then delete that Xamarin.Auth package. Make sure you update the packages to the latest version and then resubmit.

Comment: I have removed Xamarin.Auth package from my project, and updated all 3rd party libraries to it's latest versions also, but it is still showing reference in Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS, Xamarin.iOS.dll , Xamarin.iOS.pdb files
And I have used Linker Behavior to SDK Only or Link All and then added the additional arguments: --optimize=experimental-xforms-product-type, also tried force-rejected-types-removal.

Comment: Maybe there's a different issue, are you setting up everything properly? Did you put the arguments inside the Release|iPhone configuration or Debug iPhoneSimulator?

Comment: My arguments are in Release/iPhone. And to just check where it is giving me reference I have put argument in Debug/iPhoneSimulator with --optimize=experimental-xforms-product-type --warn-on-type-ref=UIKit.UIWebView. 
I have updated all my 3rd party libraries to it's latest, even VS on Mac is latest version, .NetStandard version is also updated(2.0 to 2.1), And created new POC which is having only Xamarin.Forms nuget(8.2.0.1364), not using WKWebView also, and using "grep -r UIWebView ." This POC also giving reference in Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.dll file. Can you help me please @Saamer.

Comment: @PrajaktaAhire were you able to figure it out? Can you please share a sample on GitHub with which I can replicate your issue?

Answer (score 0):

This seems an existing issue of Xamarin.forms on iOS .

1. Make sure that the version Xamarin.Forms is 4.6 or higher and Xamarin.iOS is 13.10.0.17 or higher.
2. Change the Linker Behavior to SDK Only or Link All and then add the
   additional arguments: `--optimize=experimental-xforms-product-type`
   Please check all of these have been set under the release
   configuration and iPhone platform.

For more details you could refer
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/uiwebview-deprecation-xamarin-forms/

Comment: Thank you, but I'm already have Xamarin.Forms version 4.8 and Xamarin.iOS is 13.18.2.1. Also have linker Link All with additional arguments: -optimize=experimental-xforms-product-type under Release/iPhone. And also deleted obj & bin folders from ios project but no luck at all. Is there something else I have to do?

Comment: @PrajaktaAhire did you get a solution? Are you using HockeyAppsdk,please replace it with app center.