# ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage trying to deploy admob banner using Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, admob

When I try to deploy my app I receive a mail from apple:

Dear Developer,

We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app, "Weather Location Information" 1.7.7 (1.7.7). Please correct the following issues, then upload again.

ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview).

Best regards,

The App Store Team

Im really new with Xamarin platform and I think the rejected from apple come from this class:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;


namespace WeatherLocationInfo.Controls
{
    public class AdmobControl : View
    {
    public static readonly BindableProperty AdUnitIdProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
                   nameof(AdUnitId),
                   typeof(string),
                   typeof(AdmobControl),
                   string.Empty);

    public string AdUnitId
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(AdUnitIdProperty);
        set => SetValue(AdUnitIdProperty, value);
    }
}
}
```

If I change `public class AdmobControl : View` to `public class AdmobControl : UIView` and

```
using UIKIT;
```

I receive this error on this lines: `get => (string)GetValue(AdUnitIdProperty); set => SetValue(AdUnitIdProperty, value);`

```
CS0103 The name GetValue does not exist in the current context
CS0103 The name SetValue does not exist in the current context
```

Can I get some example how to fix/update my code and deploy without reject from apple.

I fallow this [steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview?tabs=macos#uiwebview-deprecation-and-app-store-rejection-itms-90809) but apple rejected me again.
Now In additional mtouch arguments on iOS build options I try to put this line: `--optimize=force-rejected-types-removal` but they rejected me again.

I use `Xamarin.Forms(4.8.0.1451)` in my iOS project and `Xamarin.Forms(4.8.0.1821)` on my base project.

Is there a way to fix this reject from apple ?

My class AdMobViewRenderer look like this:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using Foundation;
using Google.MobileAds;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using WeatherLocationInfo.Controls;
using WeatherLocationInfo.iOS.Implementations;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AdmobControl), typeof(AdMobViewRenderer))]
namespace WeatherLocationInfo.iOS.Implementations
{
    [Protocol]
    public class AdMobViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<AdmobControl, BannerView>
    {
        [System.Obsolete]
#pragma warning disable CS0809 // Obsolete member overrides non-obsolete member
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<AdmobControl> e)
#pragma warning restore CS0809 // Obsolete member overrides non-obsolete member
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control == null)
            {
                SetNativeControl(CreateBannerView());
            }
        }



    [System.Obsolete]
#pragma warning disable CS0809 // Obsolete member overrides non-obsolete member
        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
#pragma warning restore CS0809 // Obsolete member overrides non-obsolete member
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
            Control.AdUnitID = Element.AdUnitId;
        }

    [System.Obsolete]
    private BannerView CreateBannerView()
    {
        var bannerView = new BannerView(AdSizeCons.SmartBannerPortrait)
        {
            AdUnitID = Element.AdUnitId,
            RootViewController = GetVisibleViewController()
        };

        bannerView.LoadRequest(GetRequest());

        Request GetRequest()
        {
            var request = Request.GetDefaultRequest();
            return request;
        }

        return bannerView;
    }

    private UIViewController GetVisibleViewController()
    {
        var windows = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Windows;
        foreach (var window in windows)
        {
            if (window.RootViewController != null)
            {
                return window.RootViewController;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

is the reason for the rejection by apple to be in the code of this class ?

Comment: this is a very well documented and discussed issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61613670/uiwebview-deprecation-and-app-store-rejection-on-xamarin-forms

Comment: In iOS build options I change Link Behavior to Link All and adding in additional mtouch arguments this line --optimize=experimental-xforms-product-type but they rejected me again

Comment: This not works for me !

Comment: I update my question.

Comment: something in your code or in one of the libraries you are using is referencing UIWebView.  If you have upgraded to XF 4.8 the problem is not in XF, so you need to check the other libraries you are using

Comment: In the Assembly browser from the ViewRenderer I see: public abstract class ViewRenderer<TView, TNativeView> 
How can I change TNativeView with WKWebView ?

Comment: And my Xamarin.Google.iOS.MobileAds is 7.32.0 I don't want to update it because the code is in class AdMobViewRenderer stops working.

Comment: According to Google this problem is fixed in 7.55

Comment: How can I change UIView to WKWebView in my AdMobViewRenderer class ?

Comment: What are you talking about?  This is a problem in the Google library.  Update the library to fix the problem.

Comment: When I update the library I receive message: Runtime.cs file not found.. what can I do ?

Comment: based on what you posted in previous questions, I would look at the Error window and see what it says.  I think the `Runtime.cs` is masking the real underlying issue